# How to Get Facebook Usage Statistics of a User

Tags: facebook, statistics, usage-statistics

Is there a way of which I can have someone's facebook statistics (e.g. average number of days online per week, average number of post made per week, average number of post responded per week) for a time scale of, for example, 12 weeks. I intend to make an academic paper which aims to relate personality type and frequency of facebook usage.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain the data is not available through any of the public APIs. However, the data your after could be calculated via the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/). Facebook only makes that API available to select partners, so you'll need to reach out to them in order to gain access.